# Is it possible to open this corrupted file

Tags: notebooks, warning-messages

I get the following message:

```
 There was a syntax error on line 23 in the file: 
  Petrin_methodu_ile.nb.
  The error was:
```

When I open the file I just get the info about the Mathematica version etc...

This is ridiculous. I am not using a external hardrive or anything like that.

Comment: Can you upload the file somewhere? It is not possible to give much useful information without knowing more about your file.

Comment: Ok, this must work I guess: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1crsZa3YuBVmJtQwr1CET4Zt2G3bQ0QuB

Comment: @Szabolcs Did you have a chance to take a look?

Comment: @Szabolcs something happened to the lines just a split second before I save it on Wolfram Cloud. STUPID. There should be a shortcut option in Mathematica to simultaneously save in Cloud and hardrive while keeping the last saved option reserved in same backup folder. Harddrive space is for free nowadays.

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist Storage space is not free. You are the product.

Comment: Did you have text in the notebook or only code? If you had text, was it written in a language that does not use the Roman alphabet?  It looks *really* corrupted though, may be unsalvageable ...

Comment: Open it and save it as a text file, then open it in Mathematica. There are visible fragments `Cell [CellGroupData [{` with broken encoding

Comment: Yes there is some text, I might have used a couple of letters from Turkish alphabet. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: The parts with garbled data mostly follow a pattern that repeats. I doubt it is but noise.

Comment: It uses very similar code evaluated for slightly different parameters. I guess I have to code it again.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 home eidtion

Comment: The file was originally from Wolfram Cloud

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes opening with the notepad can help me to restore some of the code.

Comment: I do not know if the home edition has [file history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17128/windows-8-file-history}? It allows to save backups to network drives. It is very useful but it has to be configured beforehand.

Comment: Turkish also uses the Roman alphabet. I was just wondering if the notebook used some weird encoding. But it does not. I would contact Wolfram Support to report the problem and ask if they can help with the garbled part. I have no idea if it can be recovered. Possibly not.

Comment: As for the non-garbled part, if you select a syntactically correct and complete bit of a cell expression, then it can be pasted into a notebook. [Here's one part I got](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhec9jbel1mdiff/buddha-notebook-bit.nb?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you all for your helps. Yes Turkish uses Roman Alphabet with some tweaks here and there. I can code it again, it will take just two days maybe.

Comment: I would contact Wolfram Support anyway. Even if the notebook is unrecoverable, they should be notified about the problem, so they can fix it and it would not happen again.

Comment: I will contact.

Comment: I am afraid this is the only usable bit I could recover. There is one more non-garbled part, but it looks like it is part of an output cell (not input). It is a huge expression, so it is truncated, and the "show more" button does not work. http://i.stack.imgur.com/4c4sJ.png  All the rest is garbled.

Comment: How to copy the text into notebook. There are some sections towards the end that can be useful. In a way that you have done for the first section.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to open corrupted notebooks (all kinds of Wolfram Files)

You may try the following:

1) In the "File" menu you click on "Open..."

2) You select "File of types" for "Wolfram Files" (this enables the "Options" button)

[image: Choose in "File of types" Wolfram Files]

3) Press "Options"

4) Enable first checkbox "Parse and load entire notebook in memory ..."

[image: opens a corrupted Wolfram File]

5) confirm and report me your experience.

The images were made under MMA 11.0.1 on Ubuntu, just for orientation

To be honest: I never tried this procedure in my life.
But this is the theory,(for rebuilding FileLeader+ FileTrailer+...) I found some times ago in the documentation.

Good luck, hieron

Comment: This will just offer to show the notebook as plain text. The notebook still can't be parsed. It's the same as opening it with a text editor.

Comment: you can open a notebook even if its file outline cache has become corrupted.

Comment: I think it depends on the type of corruption how Mathematica treats the content, but anyway it gives a standard user a convenient way for saving his work to a new notebook.

Comment: Thank you. I will check when I am back to the office on Monday.